# Connect mobile device wireless on android studio for flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, wireless

How to connect mobile device wireless android studio for flutter. I try every method but am failed. When i create emulator thy run very slow beacause I think Ram issue if any other solution please guide me thank u

Answer (score 2):

You can connect mobile device and debug wirelessly but you need both your laptop and mobile on the same network(WiFi).

follow these steps:

- Connect your mobile through a usb cable to the device and in the terminal run the command :

  ```
  adb devices
  ```
- Now you will see your attached device id, like this :

  ```
  list of devices attached
  RZ8N904WT6Y     device
  ```
- Copy the device id (RZ8N904WT6Y-in my case)
- Now start the device in tcpip port, like this :

  ```
  adb -s <device-id> tcpip 5555
  ```
- Find out the local IP address of the Android device. You can find this information by pressing/long-pressing the WiFi icon in the quick settings drop-down and then clicking the WiFi network you are connected to
- Type below command to connect to the device over WiFi:

  ```
  adb connect <IP address>:5555
  ```
- If the command ran successfully, you can now disconnect the USB cable and enjoy debugging over WiFi